# glReadPixels not updating the value

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

glReadPixels is not getting updated as soon as I draw a point.

```
  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
  glEnd();
  glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);

  printf("after coloring %d %d %d\n", (int)pixel[0], (int)pixel[1] , (int)pixel[2]);
```

The values of `pixel[0]`, `pixel[1]` and `pixel[2]` are coming out to be zero where as the expected value is `255, 0, 0`. Help me resolve this issue :)

Comment: Could you show the type of pixel?

Comment: Pixel should be of type bite have you made sure you got a right type in its declaration?

Comment: are you sure your `x,y` are corresponding to screens `(0,0)` ? Take in mind transform matrices ... screens top left corner is the image origin so is  your point rendered there?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a number of issues

- model to NDC space transformation is not set up to produce a 1:1 mapping from vertex coordinates to pixel location
- you did try to set up such a transformation, but your points end up in a neighbor pixel, due to roundoff errors and because OpenGL pixel centers are kind of unintuitive (they make sense, mathematically)
- the read buffer is not set to the buffer you're drawing to (glDrawBuffer, glReadBuffer)

Post your full code and we are able to reproduce and help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see all code but as I suppose maybe problem is that your x and y it's a float value here `glVertex2f(x,y);` and x and y is less that 1 but `glReadPixels` works with int parameter and after casting from float to int it takes not correct value of coordinates of pixel from what we want read the info so in case if you want work with real pixels coordinates you could use `glOrtho` (more info you can find in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832087/how-can-i-specify-vertices-in-pixels-in-opengl)) for example for window heigh = 500 and width = 500:

```
void Display(void) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //Rectangles();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glOrtho(0, 500, 0, 500, -1, 1); 
      // Restore the default matrix mode
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        float x = 50, y = 50;
        unsigned char pixel[3];
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
          glVertex2f(x,y);
        glEnd();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);

        printf("after coloring %d %d %d\n", (int)pixel[0], (int)pixel[1] , (int)pixel[2]);
        glFlush();
    }
```